# kafka schema with external https connection

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm beginning to despair of kafka. For a private project, a company sends me a kafka stream.
After a long time of trying, I finally managed to connect to the bootstrap servers and receive the first messages. But not deserialized. At the moment the data format looks like this:
4868fa8▒▒▒▒_9601FLHBK053A5T▒z+B▒▒▒▒▒▒

The company sends key as well as value in avro format and I also got several schema urls. But I just can't manage to use them correctly, so that I get readable data. No matter how I enter it, it always throws an error. Only when I retrieve without any schema I get the messages back like above.

The schema urls are in https and external so I already tried to create a truststore for the url. Can someone give me a hint what else I could try?

```
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka1.some.url:9093,kafka2.some.url:9093,kafka3.some.url:9093 --topic myTopic --consumer-property security.protocol=SSL --consumer-property ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2 --consumer-property ssl.truststore.location=ssl/myTruststore.jks --consumer-property ssl.truststore.password=xxx --consumer-property  ssl.keystore.location=ssl/keystore.jks --consumer-property ssl.keystore.password=xxx --consumer-property ssl.key.password=xxx --consumer-property schema.registry=https://schema-reg.some.url  --from-beginning
```

the first question that comes up here, i was told 3 urls for the schemas. one base url which i specified in the program call and two more one for key and one for value. both have the following format:

> https://schema-reg.some.url/subjects/Key/versions/latest/schema
>
> https://schema-reg.some.url/subjects/Value/versions/latest/schema

looks like (for key):

> {"type":"record","name":"WoKey","namespace":"somenameSpace","fields":[{"name":"someId","type":"string","aliases":["userId"]},{"name":"nextId","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}

Unfortunately I am totally stumped. I was also given a typescipt, but I want to use the whole thing directly in kafka and later write it to a MySQL DB via kafka-connect sink.

If i start kafka with settings above i always get an error:

> ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:
> (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 423
> at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:333)
> at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:114)
> at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:88)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter$AvroMessageDeserializer.deserialize(AvroMessageFormatter.java:133)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter.writeTo(AvroMessageFormatter.java:92)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageFormatter.writeTo(SchemaMessageFormatter.java:181)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:115)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:75)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:52)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)

Comment: The correct property is `schema.registry.url`, not `schema.registry`,and it's given with `--property` and the urls would be `/subjects/myTopic-value`, for example

Comment: Appreciate! Thanks a lot! Fantastic! @OneCricketeer

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: Yes it is working. I'm so happy. Now i will try to adopt this to connect part and write the topic into mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error says "Connection Refused", I think the problem is related to `--consumer-property schema.registry=`

The correct option is `--property schema.registry.url=https://...`

And regarding the URLs mentioned, the default subjects would have `-value` or `-key` after the topic name.

Otherwise, one suggestion would be to use `--consumer-config` with a file rather than needing to type out long command options.